# What copy is created when using advanced indexing for modifying a numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

The [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html) of `numpy`'s advanced indexing says:

> Advanced indexing always returns a copy of the data (contrast with
>   basic slicing that returns a view).

I understand this using the example code

```
tmp = np.array([0,0,0,1,1,1])
new = tmp[tmp == 0]
new[1] = 5
```

the original array `tmp` is not modified.

However, what happens when I use advanced slicing for modifying an array? For example

```
tmp = np.array([0,0,0,12,12,12,4,5,4,4])
uni = np.unique(tmp)
for info in enumerate(uni):
    tmp[tmp == info[1]] = info[0]
```

clearly, `tmp` is modified during the process, what copy is created?

Comment: No copy.  `x[..]=...` uses `__setitem__` directly

Comment: The quote applies to `x[...]` when used to fetch a value, a `__getitem__` use, not when it is used to assign values.